# How to completely reinstall gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I set the command to run when I start the terminal to reset, and now I am unable to open the terminal. I have reinstalled, purged and deleted the config files, but it's still not working. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please be more specific. Which command did you add and where did you add it?

Comment: It sounds like you checked the `Run a custom command instead of my shell` box in the profile preferences - is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I ticked that and put reset into the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `gnome-terminal --preferences` to open GNOME Terminal's Preferences dialog without opening an actual terminal. There you can fix your configuration.

In recent versions this functionality is also available in the right-click (or two-finger-click) menu of its launch icon.

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf-editor to reset the value for a custom command that you defined in your profile.

In dconf-editor, you will find the setting in a folder for your profile. The folder has a random name so will be different for everyone and looks like

```
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:a4dcd4ae-1231-4f8k-b439-d804a4d674c2/
```

In that folder, you will find a setting `custom-command`. Click it and in the new screen that appears, turn the "default" swith on. The value should now revert to ''. If not, then delete the contents in "Custom value" (which in your case should read "reset").